# Where do I find Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, assembly-resolution

A project won't compile because of a missing assembly. The file that causes the error has a

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers;
```

The `VisualStudio` part is marked in red. What do I have to install to fix it? To me it sounds like something that would have come with Visual Studio, but that is what I am using, so it is installed...

***Clarification:*** I know what assembly it exists in, and the reference is added earlier to the project references. But how do I get it? What SDK do I have to install? Or have I forgotten to check something off when I installed Visual Studio?

Comment: @adrianbanks appears to have the correct answer here. The physical assembly lives in `%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\ Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` folder (assuming VS2008). (For VS2005, change the 9.0 to 8.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to find it in the "Add Reference" dialog in the .Net tab.

If not, the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll` lives in the `Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` subdirectory of Visual Studio's installation directory. You could add it manually from there.

Comment: Apparently, it ships with Visual Studio. It might be that you turned off a feature when you installed Visual Studio which has caused it to not be present.

Comment: In VS2012 I found it in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0

Answer (score 7):

For Visual Studio 2010 the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers` assembly exists under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0` (or relevant Program Files root).

For a debugger visualizer to target Visual Studio 2010 it must reference the 10.0 version of this assembly or it will fail with an invalid cast exception.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find the assembly under the ".NET" list of assemblies in the "Add Reference" dialog.

Comment: The current Debugger Visualizers walkthrough (as of late 2018) is for Visual Studio 2017 for a project targeting .NET Standard, and the Add Reference dialog no-longer has a tab named ".NET" - in fact all the tabs are now empty except for manual filesystem browse.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone still looking for this - it's been moved to [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VSSDK.DebuggerVisualizers/)

Comment: This doesn't look legit.

Comment: Note that this version hasn't been updated since 2014, which would be VS 2013.